# pandas index row delete specific values and update column

Tags: python, pandas

I added extra info to top of csv file, as extra row, but now when I read it, it can't find column name as Key, how do delete extra row from csv file which I added

[image]

My columns show `Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'extra_col1', 'extra_col2', 'Unnamed: 3', 'Unnamed: 4'], dtype='object')`

But I want to remove row `'extra_col1', 'extra_col2'`

so csv should be like below and I can use Col1 as Key
[image]

print(df.iloc[0])

```
Unnamed: 0     NaN
extra_col1    Col1
extra_col2    Col2
Unnamed: 3    Col3
Unnamed: 4    Col4
```

So if I try to use drop it is removing Col1, I just want to remove extra row at the top

Comment: Try using `skiprows=1` while reading your csv. Refer [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for more info.